# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'emp'

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

The emp database I created using MySQL and its path is "C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.28\data\emp".
The emp database is having only one table "books".
Here is the Java code to view the field inside the books table.

```
    import java.sql.*;
    public class JDBCDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try{
                Connection myConn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp","root","");
                Statement myStat=myConn.createStatement();
                ResultSet res=myStat.executeQuery("select * from books");
                while(res.next()){
                    System.out.println(res.getString("id")+" "+res.getString("title"));
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

It is thowing an error

```
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'emp'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at jdbcdemo.JDBCDemo.main(JDBCDemo.java:23)
```

But the above code error is throwing errs because it is unable to access the emp database.
How can I get the path to the database?

Comment: How did you create the database? --- The fact that you think the file system path has anything to do with connecting to the database, makes me suspect you created it wrong.

Comment: @Andreas using MySQL.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database using GUI tools like MySQL Workbench?

Comment: That didn't answer my question. I already know you're using MySQL. I asked *how* you created the database. What UI or command did you use? Edit the question and show the steps you took to create the database (not the steps to install MySQL, but the steps to create the `emp` database).

Comment: Pradeep I don't use MySQL Workbench I created this table through the cmd and yes through I can access the emp database.

Comment: @Andreas using cmd mysql>create database emp; then mysql>use emp; And then i create a table books.

Comment: So if you run `SHOW DATABASES;` on the mysql prompt, the `emp` database is listed?

Comment: @Andreas yes its showing when I use mysql>show databases;

Comment: When you did your research and did a web search for the error, e.g. [`mysql Unknown database`](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+Unknown+database+), none of the many articles found was helpful?

Comment: @Andreas i did some searching most of them went over my head.